# Failure to register a OneDrive file handler

Tags: onedrive

I have been attempting to register a OneDrive [File Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/register-manually?view=odsp-graph-online) as [demonstrated](https://github.com/OneDrive/o365-markdown-file-handler-v2) on GitHub.

My initial PUT seems to work but I get very flaky results when I attempt to update.  I have one domain where the handler works fine but another where I get these problems:

- refresh works first time but not subsequently
- refresh seems to work but handler not evident in OneDrive
- change and update handler but changes not seen when I refresh

Is there any way to work out what is going on?   The responses I get in Postman indicate that everything has worked but the file handler is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some observations which may help anyone else who stumbles on this:

- the forceRefresh requests seems very patchy, I can make a change in the handler manifest and only some hours later will forceRefresh actually return the changed manifest
- don't make the silly mistake I did and change the version in the handler manifest to something other than 2.  If you do this the manifest will upload successfully but your handler will never appear. An error response would be much nicer than a silent fail.
- I often find that even once forceRefresh has worked the new handler does not appear in my browser.  To fix this I go to Local Storage (in the browser dev tools) and remove the entry for 'fileHandlerCache', then do a refresh.

BTW, handlers seem like a great way to extend OneDrive but I have found the developer experience to be pretty rough.  Any chance of a smoother ride?